# Hiding html video controls on iOS devices

Tags: html, ios, video, device

I have a video on my website which autoplays as a background. However, on iOS devices, autoplay is no longer supported. Instead, I would like to show the poster fallback on those devices. The only problem is, you can still see a play button. Here is my code:

```
<video autoplay loop muted preload poster="<?php echo $poster_src; ?>">
  <source src="<?php echo $video_mp4; ?>" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="<?php echo $video_webm; ?>" type="video/webm">
  <source src="<?php echo $video_ogg; ?>" type="video/ogg">
</video>
```

As you can see, there's no controls in there and on desktop that is working fine. How do I get rid of the controls on iOS devices?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use media query to detect IOS device:

For instance this one:

iPad 1 & 2 in landscape

```
  @media only screen 
    and (min-device-width : 768px) 
    and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
    and (orientation : landscape)
    and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1)  
{ 
yourControl {
 visibility: hidden;
}
}
```

Comment: I could, but I would rather prevent the dom element for the controls from being created altogether.

Comment: so you can use user-agent in javascript and remove/hide them, does it looke better for you?

Answer (score 0):

the device using iOS is iPad and iPhone, so you should detect the browser/device type first,

```html
<?php
    $browser_type = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
    $controls  = "controls";
    if(preg_match('/iphone|ipad/i', $browser_type))
    {
        $controls = "";
    }
?>

<video autoplay loop muted preload <?php echo $controls ?> poster="<?php echo $poster_src; ?>">
  <source src="<?php echo $video_mp4; ?>" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="<?php echo $video_webm; ?>" type="video/webm">
  <source src="<?php echo $video_ogg; ?>" type="video/ogg">
</video>
```